# Django: DeferredAttribute object / choices field as string value to modify Context in class based ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

In my template I would like to display a long name, however, I don't save the full name in the database, only a reference number.

My attempted solution is to convert the Choices Tuple into a Dictionary

```
prd_dic = dict(PRODUCTS)
```

Then I call the Value in the dictionary with the Key

```
name = prd_dic['0000']
```

In my list View, I modify the Context to feed the full name into the Template

```
context['product_name'] = name
```

When I pass an object into a place a string is expected a KeyError is raised (using DeferredAttribute object).

My question is, is there a built in function to solve above, either in the View as a function to convert and feed into the Context, OR as making this conversion on the Model directly?

The idea is to convert saved number into a full name according a key table to be displayed in Template.

Thankful for some input.

```
PRODUCTS = (
    ('0000'   ,   'Hamburger'),
    ('1111'   ,   'Pizza')
)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=PRODUCTS, blank=True, null=True)

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product/product_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        prd_obj = Product.product_number # this is an object
        prd_dic = dict(PRODUCTS)
        name = prd_dic[prd_obj] # a single string, prd_dic['0000'] works in template
        context['product_name'] = name
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get_product_number_display` is automatically defined for you; you can call it directly from the template, with no need to override `get_context_data`.

See [the docs on `get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).